# Запятая перед союзом с присоединительным значением?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

**Ожесточился фараон, не поверил Моисею(,) и не отпустил евреев.**

- Есть ли правило, объясняющую постановку этой запятой?
- Почему хочется поставить? Когда читаешь предложение, произносится пауза после "Моисею"; не читается подряд: не поверил Моисею и не отпустил евреев. Формально здесь однородные сказуемые, но смыслового равноправия не чувствуется: не отпустил — как следствие того, что не поверил, то есть не одновременно: не поверил и не отпустил. Получается предложение (или часть предложения?) с присоединительным союзом.

Из правил [вот что](https://studopedia.org/12-51749.html) удалось найти: *некоторые сочи­нительные союзы (и, да, или, а, но, однако) употребляются в присоедини­тельном значении. В этом случае они присоединяют добавочные мысли, явля­ющиеся: а) следствием, выводом... Перед союзами с присоединительным зна­чением голос понижается и делается пауза*. Правда, в правиле речь о сложных предложениях, а здесь ситуация с однородными сказуемыми. 
Аргумент это или не аргумент? Можно запятую поставить, или это недопустительная вольность?

Comment: Здесь есть присоединительное значение?! *Я играю, пою, и танцую тоже.* Вот где присоединительное значение, вот где ставится запятая.

Comment: >> *Получается предложение (или часть предложения?) с присоединительным союзом.* В конце концов, поставьте тире. Но по-прежнему считаю, что "присоединительность" здесь высосана из пальца.

Comment: Порядок перечисления событий странный, поэтому трудно судить о знаках препинания. Корректно: фараон не поверил Моисею, (поэтому) ожесточился и не отпустил  евреев.

Comment: Если при замыкающем союзе И сохраняется перечислительная интонация, то и при отсутствии запятой перед И перед последним однородным членом будет делаться ПАУЗА. А присоединительного значения здесь нет. Розенталь о замыкающем союзе http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Союз **и** имеет замыкающее значение, если в составе сложного предложения первые его части соединены бессоюзной связью, а последняя связана союзом **и**: *Гремят раскаты молодые, вот дождик брызнул, пыль летит, повисли перлы дождевые, и солнце нити золотит* (Ф. Тютчев).

**[источник](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/sredstva-svyazi-chastey-slojnosochinennyih-70923.html)**

Но у нас нет сложного предложения. Фараон ожесточился, не поверил и не отпустил.

Не надобно запятой.